# Talend Identity and Access Management for Talend Cloud

Tags: amazon-iam, talend

We are using the Talend Cloud version, so, there is TMC (Talend Management Console) instead of TAC. We need to set up authentication and authorization for our ESB services, but it is impossible within TMC. We have found **Talend Identity and Access Management**, but no idea if it is used for only TAC or TMC as well. Could you inform me if this Talend IAM supports TMC or not, if yes then how? If not, then which tool could be used instead?

Kind Regards

Comment: You might want to add some more detail and context to this question, explain the acronyms you're using and describe what it is you want to authenticate e.g. users, services.

Comment: We are setting up ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) and Talend (https://www.talend.com/) is a company providing open source and enterprise solutions. Within ESB we have rest services and we want to control authentication and authorization for those services.
Talend uses Apache Karaf for running those services. It also provided Talend Identity and Access Management tool, but depending on the application (and version) we use, we want to know the compatibility and possibility to use that existing tool.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that TIA is a white labeled version of Apache Syncope. Using on-premise Talend (i.e. TAC) you could install this on the same server running TAC, however as you are using Talend Cloud this isn't an option.
It looks like you are going to need a server of some description to run TIA on, if you are using Remote Engines (which I think you much be as I don't think you can run ESB jobs on Cloud Engines yet) then I recommend you install TIA (or even the latest version of Apache Syncope as Talend can sometimes ship some pretty ancient versions of software they have white-labeled) on a remote engine.
As far as I can tell there should be no reason why your ESB jobs shouldn't be able to use TIA (or Syncope) provided the appropriate firewall rules are in place.

Comment: Talend IAM is not available anymore as a product. So, I cannot download it from talend website. Regarding direct integration of Apache Karaf (Talend uses for hosting services) to Apache Syncope I will check the possibility. Thanks.